# Swift Custom Call Out WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uiview, wkwebview

I created a custom call out with a UIView inside of it. I think I am getting everything correct so far by sending the URL's (haven't tested it yet, just judging) but my problem is setting up the WKWebView. I am just unsure how to call the UIView from the file and then setup the WKWebView inside "DidSelect MKAnnotationView". So that's my problem, calling the UIView inside "DidSelect" and setting it up as WKWebView.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

    if view.annotation is MKUserLocation { return }

    let customAnnotation = view.annotation as! CustomBusinessPoint
    let views = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomBusinessCallOut", owner: nil, options: nil)
    let calloutView = views?[0] as! CustomBusinessCallOut

    calloutView.goToProfile.addTarget(self, action:#selector(handleRegister(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    calloutView.browserView.addSubview(webview!)

    calloutView.websiteURL.addTarget(self, action:#selector(businessWebsite(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    calloutView.facebookURL.addTarget(self, action:#selector(businessFacebook(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    calloutView.twitterURL.addTarget(self, action:#selector(businessTwitter(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    calloutView.instagramURL.addTarget(self, action:#selector(businessInstagram(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    calloutView.googleURL.addTarget(self, action:#selector(businessGoogle(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    calloutView.yelpURL.addTarget(self, action:#selector(businessYelp(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    calloutView.foursquareURL.addTarget(self, action:#selector(businessFoursquare(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    calloutView.snapchatURL.addTarget(self, action:#selector(businessSnapchat(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    calloutView.businessName.text = customAnnotation.businessName


    calloutView.center = CGPoint(x: view.bounds.size.width / 2, y: -calloutView.bounds.size.height * -0.0001)
    view.addSubview(calloutView)
    mapView.setCenter((view.annotation?.coordinate)!, animated: true)
}


func businessWebsite(sender: UIButton) {
    if let dictionary = locationData! as? [String: AnyObject],
        let businessWebsite = dictionary["businessWebsite"] as? String,
        let url = NSURL(string: businessWebsite) {
        let request = NSURLRequest(url: url as URL)
        self.webView?.load(request as URLRequest)
    } else {
        print("No value")
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {() -> Void in
            CommonUtils.sharedUtils.hideProgress()
            CommonUtils.sharedUtils.showAlert(self, title: "Ooops!", message: "This location does not have a website")
        })
    }

}
```

Comment: You want to call this function "businessWebsite"  from didSelect method?

Comment: I am trying to wire up UIButtons so inside the callout view that user can select different URLS to change the webview and view those pages